# Django Rest Framework basic set of APIs around authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm a django newby and I'm looking to expose basic services like: forgotten password, password change.

I would expect to have those services for free but looking here and there it looks like we have to do them by hand, is that correct?

Is there any explanation for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of the services you mentioned is different in each project and is completely dependent on the project's requirements, and Django and DRF have only prepared a platform that you can implement as you wish. So you either have to implement it yourself or use libraries that have done it for you. You can find the list of these libraries in the DRF documentation website ([here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages)).